# Problem facing while killing a button

Tags: android, button

This problem might be simple, but I am not able to figure it out. The is the button which I am using should be killed after it is first used. After clicking the button once, it should not work again. It should do the required work once and become dummy after clicking it.

Can any one help in this concern?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your button not clickable inside your `OnClickListener()`

```
button.setClickable(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Button.setEnabled(false);` to disable it in your click listener.